# AWS Micro instance vs Large instance: Cost Efficiency

Tags: amazon-ec2

It seems for the cost of running 2 large instances, I can run about 40 micro instances. In a distributed system (MongoDB in my case), 40 micro instances sounds a lot faster than 2 large instances, assume the database file is on EBS in both cases.

It this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Micro instances may have 97% CPU "steal" time, and they can be unresponsive for several seconds.

In many use cases it's not acceptable to have to wait 15 seconds for a reply. I think small instances are the best deal. I run several of them and I divide the risk of problems and the load among them.

source: personal experience and [this article](http://gregsramblings.com/2011/02/07/amazon-ec2-micro-instance-cpu-steal/)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that MongoDB has limitations under 32bit which means that most people cant run it on a small instance.